# Inverse limit of sequence of fibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I'm reading through the proof of Proposition 4.67 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and I've come to something that I'm having trouble understanding.

For an arbitrary sequence of fibrations $... \rightarrow\ X_2 \rightarrow\ X_1$, I need  to show that the natural map $\lambda: \pi_i(\varprojlim X_n) \rightarrow\ \varprojlim \pi_i(X_n)$ is injective if the maps $\pi_{i+1}(X_n) \rightarrow\ \pi_{i+1}(X_{n-1})$ are surjective for all $n$.

If $f: S^i \rightarrow\ \varprojlim X_n$ is in $Ker \lambda$, then each component map $f_n: S^i \rightarrow\ X_n$ is nullhomotopic. So for each $n$, there exists $F_n: D^{i+1} \rightarrow\ X_n$ such that $F_n$ restricted to $S^i$ is $f_n$. If $F_n$ can be homotoped so that $F_{n-1} = p_nF_{n}$, where $p_n: X_n \rightarrow\ X_{n-1}$ is from the sequence of fibrations, then induction on $n$ yields the result.

From the definition of the inverse limit, $F_{n-1} = p_nF_{n}$ on $S^i$, so by gluing the two disks $p_nF_n: D^{i+1} \rightarrow\ X_{n-1}$ and $F_{n-1}: D^{i+1} \rightarrow\ X_{n-1}$ together along $S^i$, it is possible to construct a map $g_{n-1}: S^{n+1} \rightarrow\ X_{n-1}$.

According to Hatcher, the surjectivity of $\pi_{i+1}(X_n) \rightarrow\ \pi_{i+1}(X_{n-1})$ implies that there exists $G_n: D^{i+1} \rightarrow\ X^n$ such that $G^n$ restricted to $S^i$ is $f_n$ and $p_nG_n$ is homotopic rel $S^i$ to $F_{n-1}$.

Why is this true? If $\pi_{i+1}(X_n) \rightarrow\ \pi_{i+1}(X_{n-1})$, then there exists $g_{n}: S^{i+1} \rightarrow\ X_{n}$ such that $p_ng_n$ is homotopic to $g_{n-1}$, but I see no way to get the desired $G_n$ from $g_n$. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, I have trouble finding out what is the needed argument, but I'll try to give another one. I will consistently use radial coordinates on the disk, ie. $(r, \phi) \in D^{k}$, where $r$ is the distance from the centre and $\phi \in S^{k-1}$.

Let $\tilde{F}_{n-1}: S^{i} \times I \rightarrow X_{n-1}$ given by $\tilde{F}_{n-1}(\phi, t) = F_{n-1}(t-1, \phi)$ be the contracting homotopy. By the fibration property there exists a lift of this homotopy to $X_{n}$, say $G_{n}$, such that $G_{n} |_{S^{i} \times \{ 0 \}} = f_{n}$.

Let  $g_{n} = G_{n} |_{S^{i} \times \{ 1 \}}$. Since $\tilde{F}_{n-1} |_{S^{i} \times \{ 1 \}}$ maps to the basepoint, we see that the image of $g_{n}$ is contained in the fibre $F \subseteq X_{n}$. The map $\pi_{i+1}(X_{n}) \rightarrow \pi_{i+1}(X_{n-1})$ is surjective and hence by the long exact sequence of homotopy the map $\pi_{i}(F) \rightarrow \pi_{i}(X_{n})$ is injective. Since $g_{n}$ is null in $\pi_{i}(X_{n})$ (being homotopic to $f_{n}$), it must be also null in $F$ and thus there is a contracting homotopy $H_{n}: S^{i} \times I \rightarrow F$.

Now define a map $F ^\prime _{n}: D^{i+1} \rightarrow X_{n}$ by

$F ^\prime _{n}(r, \phi) = G_{n}(\phi, 2(1-r))$ for $r \geq \frac{1}{2}$

$F ^\prime _{n}(r, \phi) = H_{n}(\phi, 2(\frac{1}{2}-r))$ for $r \leq \frac{1}{2}$,

After a moment of thought, we see that $p_{n} F^\prime _{n}$ is homotopic to $F_{n-1}$. Using the homotopy lifting for $(D^{i+1}, S^{i})$ we may deform it $rel \ S^{i}$ to a map $F_{n}$ such that $p_{n} F_{n} = F_{n-1}$, which is what we wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured something along the lines of Hatcher's proof! I have been able to construct this $G_n$ such that $p_nG_n \simeq F_{n-1}$ but this homotopy does not fix $S^i$. However, we can still get by without it. We will use the following claim.

**claim:** For any $[\phi] \in \pi_q(Y,y_0)$ and for any map $f \colon (D^q, *) \to (Y,y_0)$, there is a map $f' \colon (D^q, *) \rightarrow (Y,y_0)$ such that $f|_{S^{q-1}} = f'|_{S^{q-1}}$ and $ [f\cup f']=[\phi] $, where $f \cup f' \colon (D^q \cup_{S^{q-1}} D^q , *) \to (Y,y_0).$

**proof of claim:** Consider $D^q$ as the upper hemisphere $S^q_+$, so that $f \colon S^q_+ \to Y$. Define a map on the lower hemisphere $\bar f \colon S^q_- \to Y$ by projecting vertically to the upper hemisphere and then going through $f$, i.e. by the formula
$$\bar f(x_1 , \dots , x_q) := f(x_1, \dots , - x_q).$$
Then the map $f\cup \bar f \colon S^q \to Y$ extends to a map of the disk, so it is null homotopic. Then we have $[\phi]+[f \cup \bar f] = [\phi] $. Recall that the sum of these classes is represented by, the composition 
$$S^q \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} S^q \vee (S^q_+ \cup S^q_-) \stackrel{\phi \vee (f\cup \bar f)}{\longrightarrow} Y $$
We will then identify $D^{q} $ with $p^{-1}(S^q\vee S^q_-)$ and define $f'$ to be the restriction of the above composition to $D^q$. end of proof ///

Once we constructed this map $g_{n-1} \colon S^{i+1} \to X_{n-1}$, we use the surjectivity of $(p_n)_* \colon \pi_{i+1}(X_n) \to \pi_{i+1}(X_{n-1})$ to lift $[g_n]$ to a class $[g_n] \in \pi_{i+1}(X_n)$. We then apply the claim to this class and the original null homotopy $F_n : D^{i+1} \to X_n$, to obtain a map $G_n \colon D^{i+1} \to X_n$ such that $F_n |_{S^i} = G_n |_{S^i}$ and $[F_n \cup G_n] = [g_n]$. This map $G_n$ will be our new null homotopy. Observe that $(p_n)_* ([F_n \cup G_n]) = [p_nF_n \cup p_nG_n] = [g_n].$ But recall that $g_n= p_nF_n \cup F_{n-1}$, so there is a homotopy 
$$H\colon (D^{i+1} \cup_{S^{i}}D^{i+1})\times I \to X_{n-1}$$
which restricts on the second hemisphere to a homotopy from $p_nG_n$ to $F_{n-1}$.

Now we will see that we don't actually need this homotopy to fix the circle (although if anyone sees a way to force it to, that would be cleaner). Using the lifting property of $p_n$, we obtain a map $K_n \colon D^{i+1} \to X_n$ such that $p_nK_n = F_{n-1}$ and $f_n \simeq K_n|_{S^{i}}$ . Lets use $k_n$ to denote this restriction. The issue now is that the components $\{ \dots ,f_{n+1}, k_n , f_{n-1}, \dots, f_1 \}$ no longer define a map $S^i\rightarrow \varprojlim X_i$ since $p_{n+1} f_{n+1}\neq k_n$. But these maps are homotopic, and that is good enough since we can replace $f_{n+1}$ with a homotopic map $k_{n+1}$ using the lifting property of $p_{n+1}$ so that $p_{n+1} k_{n+1} = k_n$. Letting induction roll this process out to infinity, we have created a map $k \colon S^{i} \rightarrow \varprojlim X_n$ which is homotopic to our original map $f$, which extends to a $K : D^{i+1} \rightarrow \varprojlim X_n$.